# Get Thread ID in SBCL

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

I am working with Lisp sb-thread package. When I use `*current-thread*` to get the thread id, the result of the last evaluated expression is also returned with the thread id. I only need the thread id for my program.

Comment: `sb-thread:*current-thread*` is the thread object itself, not an ID...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SBCL has `setf`-able [thread](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/#Threading) *names*, not *IDs*:

```
(sb-thread:thread-name SB-THREAD:*CURRENT-THREAD*)
==> "main thread"
```

What do you need the ID for?

Comment: It's an assignment which I have. I need to show that different functions are executed on different threads.

Comment: In that case the printed representation of thread objects or their names should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

There are situations in life when you desperately need the thread's ID, for example: 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/sbcl/+bug/1751562

> "I had a situation where on SBCL on Linux, I had multiple worker
>   threads on my machine, and one of them was taking 100% of my CPU. I
>   wanted to retrieve the thread object of the offending thread, but this
>   turned out to be non-trivial."

```
(defun thread-real-id () 
 (sb-alien:alien-funcall 
    (sb-alien:extern-alien "syscall" 
    ;; sb-alien:unsigned is the return value's type and int is the parameter's type
                           (function sb-alien:unsigned int))
    ;; if on your system it returns 0xFFFFFFFF then try 186 instead of 224
    ;; or check the right gettid syscall value for your system. 
    224))

(ql:quickload :bordeaux-threads)

(let ((top-level *standard-output*)) 
  (bt:make-thread (lambda() 
                    (format top-level "my id is ~A~%" (thread-real-id)))))

; output:
my id is 657
```

In the man pages syscall function's prototype is `long syscall(long number, ...)` so the correct type for both the parameter and the ret value is LONG, but I'm not sure how to specify it using the sb-alien: types

I checked out the sbcl's src:

```
find . -name "*alien*" -exec echo {} \; -exec grep define-alien-type-tr {} \;
```

## search results:

```
./host-alieneval.lisp
  (defun %define-alien-type-translator (name translator)
(define-alien-type-translator system-area-pointer ()
(define-alien-type-translator signed (&optional (bits sb!vm:n-word-bits))
(define-alien-type-translator integer (&optional (bits sb!vm:n-word-bits))
(define-alien-type-translator unsigned (&optional (bits sb!vm:n-word-bits))
(define-alien-type-translator boolean (&optional (bits sb!vm:n-word-bits))
(define-alien-type-translator enum (&whole
(define-alien-type-translator single-float ()
(define-alien-type-translator double-float ()
(define-alien-type-translator * (to &environment env)
(define-alien-type-translator array (ele-type &rest dims &environment env)
(define-alien-type-translator struct (name &rest fields &environment env)
(define-alien-type-translator union (name &rest fields &environment env)
(define-alien-type-translator function (result-type &rest arg-types
(define-alien-type-translator values (&rest values &environment env)
# not sure which of them is the type for LONG
```

To see the threads you can use this command:

```
ps -To pid,tid -p `pidof sbcl`
```

; if you need the PID do `(sb-posix:getpid)` or call the "getpid" alien:

```
(sb-alien:alien-funcall 
   (sb-alien:extern-alien "getpid" 
       (function sb-alien:unsigned)) )
```

## If you are on Windows you could use the following code ( taken from here: https://www.linux.org.ru/forum/development/11998951 )

```
#|
typedef struct pthread_thread {
  pthread_fn start_routine;
  void* arg;
  HANDLE handle;
...
}
|#

(defun get-thread-handle (thread)
  "Retrieves WIN32 thread HANDLE from SBCL thread"
  (declare (type sb-thread:thread thread))
  (let* ((pthread-pointer
           (sb-sys:int-sap (sb-thread::thread-os-thread thread)))
         (pthread-alien
           (sb-alien:sap-alien
            pthread-pointer (sb-alien:struct nil
                                             (start-addr (* t))
                                             (arg (* t))
                                             (handle (* t))))))
    (sb-alien:alien-sap (sb-alien:slot pthread-alien 'handle))))

(defun get-thread-id (thread)
  "Retrieves WIN32 thread ID from SBCL thread"
  (declare (type sb-thread:thread thread))
  (sb-alien:alien-funcall
   (sb-alien:extern-alien "GetThreadId" (function sb-alien:unsigned
                                                  (* t)))
   (get-thread-handle thread)))

(get-thread-id sb-thread:*current-thread*) ; ==> 62
```

## *Update* It turns out that the windows code above can also be reduced to a one liner:

```
(sb-alien:alien-funcall (sb-alien:extern-alien "GetCurrentThreadId" (function sb-alien:unsigned)))
```